# Laravel Resource destroy via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

Can I use resource via ajax? I have this resource

`Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashBoardController');`

**js file**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'delete',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {id:id},
    url: " {!! route('dashboard.destroy') !!} ",
    success: function (data) {
             //
             } 
});
```

but I receive,

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Answer (score 5):

A destroy method is using a `DELETE request`, but it actually uses `POST` request within an `_method` as parameter, so your `javascript` section should looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        id: id,
        _method: 'DELETE'
    },
    url: "{!! route('dashboard.destroy') !!}",
    success: function (data) {
        //
    } 
});
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: It works also if you specify the method directly, I use it sometimes.