# I want to delete an entry using ajax in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I want to delete an entry using ajax in laravel 5.8 but every time i get an errors like csrf token mismatch or post method not allowed or delete method not allowed.

I got a solution for all above problems.but now i am getting errors in deleting data.I am using model for deleting data not controller.I am using $(model_name)->(model_function) to use model in controller.I have successfully added data using this method but now i am getting error.I have attached my  code and screenshot of error below.I have used another model in my current model.Table used in database is user table.

**View.blade.php**

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<button class='delete_user' data-id="{{ $item->id }}">Delete</button>
```

**ajax.js**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).on('click','.delete_user',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: "ajax/"+ id,
        data: {
            '_token': token,
            'id': id
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("ASD");
        }
    });
});
```

**ajaxcontroller.php**

```
public function destroy(ajax $ajax,$id)
    {
        $data = $ajax->delete_user($id);
        echo json_encode($data);
   }
```

**ajax.php**

```
public function delete_user($id)
    {
        if(user::find($id)->delete()){
            echo true;
        }else{
            echo false;
        }
    }

Route::resource('ajax', 'ajaxController');
```

I expected 1,but i got

> an error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'ajax.ajaxes' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from 'ajaxes' where `id` =
>   52 limit 1)"

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PPwR.png)

Comment: Can you show us your controller route?

Comment: Route::resource('ajax', 'ajaxController');

Comment: DELETE    | ajax/{ajax}      | ajax.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ajaxController@destroy | web

Comment: Can you share your table name? It is clear from the error that laravel is seraching for `ajaxes` inside your database. But it is missing.

Comment: table name is users

Comment: Just add following line in your model `protected $table = 'users';` it will work for you.

Comment: But the action is not event reaching model .it's stuck in controller.

Comment: No It is reaching to model, In your controller you are using `destroy(ajax $ajax,$id)` what is ajax? Is it model for Users table?

Comment: It is for calling ajax model and in that model i am doing all my database operations and in that  model i am using user model to perform delete operation.

Comment: change your model name to `User.php`

Comment: I know that i can change model name but i am here for a solution that can be useful in all situations

Comment: Then go through Table Names block at  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models. You should use `protected $table = 'users';`

Comment: @Omi I have already used that line,still errors.

Comment: could you please post your error

Comment: "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController::destroy(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected"

Comment: Change your route to `Route::delete('/ajax/{id}','ajaxcontroller@destroy')`

Comment: We use resource for reduction in code and effort.

Comment: Then change your ajax request like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389669/laravel-resource-destroy-via-ajax

Comment: Thanks @Omi your link is my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View.blade.php

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<button class='delete_user' data-id="{{ $item->id }}">Delete</button>
```

ajax.js

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).on('click','.delete_user',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
        $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "ajax/"+id,
    data: {
        _token: token,
        _method: 'DELETE',
        id: id,
    },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("ASD");
        }
    });
});
```

ajaxcontroller.php
    ```php

````
public function destroy(request $request,ajax $ajax)
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $data = $ajax->delete_user($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```
````

ajax.php

```php
    public function delete_user($id)
    {
        $data = user::findOrFail($id)->delete();
        if($data == TRUE){
            return $data;
        }else{
            echo false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not the right answer.It still gives an error about undefined variable ajax.

Comment: Don't use $ajax. Instead use $request, I have edited the code please check it now.

Comment: Method Illuminate\Http\Request::delete_user does not exist."

Comment: Use "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" at the beginning of your controller.
I have mentioned it above.
Try this you error will get resolve.

Comment: I don't have to add it manually.It's been there when i created controller.

Comment: @ShubhamDeveloper you are wrong, there is no method on $request as delete_user()
When you use a model by default it is bind with the table.
when you use $ajax->delete_user($id); the Ajax model will look for table ajaxes.
so in your model, you'll have to specify the table to use, as table ajaxes is not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Take below function as a reference and make changes in your function.Hopefully, It should work.

```
public function remove(Request $request)
{
    //
    $inputs = $request->all();
    // dd($inputs);
    $serviceid = $request->service_id;
    $delete = $request->ListDoc;
    // dd($updates);
    $update = DB::table('files')->where('service_id', $serviceid)->where('filename',$delete)->delete();
    // dd($updates);
    $posts = 'You have removed this document from the list succesfully';
    // return back()->with('success','you have updated it');
    return response()->json(array('posts'=>$posts), 200);


}
```

Comment: Yes as I am grabbing id through Request Method and using DB with table name to delete that particular  Id row. Because in laravel sometimes Model dosn't work for deleting data as they have mentioned in their documentation.

Comment: Sorry i don't know that but i still don't know why it is throwing error like this as i am just calling a function from model.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function delete_user($id)
    {
        if(DB::table('table_name')->where('id',$id)->delete()){
            echo true;
        }else{
            echo false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not reaching model.